# Delphi / RAD Studio tooltip extended view

Tags: delphi, tooltip

I currently have Delphi 2007 and Delphi XE installed on my laptop. 
The pop-up code insight tooltip view is limited  in the XE installation.
I seem to remember that this is in the editor options somewhere, but can't find it.

Can somebody please tell me where I turn on the extended tooltip view?

See image attached - D2007 on top , DXE below
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in Delphi 2009 it is called 'Tooltip Help Insight', and is found at

*Editor Options* / *Code Insight* / *Automatic features*:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ok , thanks. Unfortunatly this is already selected, and it's not working. Looks like a bug or a conflict with something else I have installed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Besides "Tooltip Expression Evaluation" and "Tooltip Help Insight" settings, also check if you have these packages loaded/installed:

- $(BDS)\Bin\dbkdebugideXXX.bpl
- $(BDS)\bin\dbkdebugproideXXX.bpl

where XXX varies according to your Delphi version.

If you are using Delphi XE+ versions you can download Delphi Distiller and check them. They are called:

- Embarcadero DBK Debugger IDE Package, and
- Embarcadero DBK Debugger Professional IDE Package

Answer (score 0):

Andreas answered my question correctly, however this did not solve my problem. 
Help insight worked correctly when triggered by Ctrl-Shift-H , but not on mouse hover, even though the Tooltip Help Insight was ticked. Re-booting etc did not help, however reinstalling XE Update 1 fixed the problem.