# Delphi XE4 IDE debug tips have stopped showing

Tags: delphi

I have been using XE4 for quite a while. Yesterday things were fine, today they are not. Specifically, when running an app within the IDE in Debug mode, the little popup hints/tips that appear when you hover your mouse cursor over a part of your code (e.g., a variable) no longer appears. Say for instance with the code below I set a breakpoint on line 56. Then I run the app. When code execution hits line 56, I used to be able to hover my mouse over the variable "a" and its value would appear in a little popup hint.  Today, it no longer does. Why might that be? I did not change any configuration options.

```
56  a := a + 1;
57  ShowMessage(IntToStr(a));
58  a := a - 1;
```

Notes: I did not hit "Run without debugging". I always press F9 to run my app within the IDE. I have exited and restarted XE4, but I have not rebooted. I have rebuilt the project numerous times.

Comment: This has always been a spontaneous issue with almost all versions of the Delphi IDE. It's just flaky.

Comment: Did you maybe hit `Run Without Debugging` instead of `Run`?

Comment: Does this problem persist after rebooting your machine and doing a full build of the project?

Comment: @GrizzlyManBear:  But if the OP did that, it wouldn't stop at a breakpoint, would it?  Or maybe I'm missing you oint ...

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.

Comment: Please check my other answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618841/delphi-rad-studio-tooltip-extended-view/32366966#32366966

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the PC resolved the issue.